# Convert map to struct

Tags: go

Ok, the title is a little bit misleading. What I'm after is as follows:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    id   int
    name string
    age  int
}

func CreateFromMap(m map[string]interface{}) (MyStruct, error) {
    var (
        id   int
        name string
        age  int
        ok   bool
    )
    err := errors.New("Error!")
    id, ok = m["id"].(int)
    if !ok {
        return nil, err
    }
    name, ok = m["name"].(string)
    if !ok {
        return nil, err
    }
    age, ok = m["age"].(int)
    if !ok {
        return nil, err
    }
    return MyStruct{id, name, age}, nil
}
```

**Don't ask:** Why I'm not using `CreateFromMap(int, string, int)`. That object comes from somewhere else, out of my control.

It's already boring to map each key, value pair in the map to struct properties. But checking if everything is `ok` or not after each conversion is chaotic.

Is there an easier way of doing this other than reflection?

Comment: Why don't you want to use reflection? Performance issues?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out if Go has merits over C other than readability, having reflection and goroutines. Lots of language features are missing and it works on top of a garbage collector. 

Other than that, I couldn't find a (un)marshaller that behaves as I want it to and too lazy to write my own.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say I assume you don't want to use reflection because you don't want to do it yourself. In this case, what about using an [external package](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) that does it for you ?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"

type MyStruct struct {
    Id   int
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    var m = make(map[string]interface{})
    m["Id"] = 17
    m["Name"] = "foo"
    m["Age"] = 42
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", m)

    res, err := CreateFromMap(m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", res)
}

func CreateFromMap(m map[string]interface{}) (MyStruct, error) {
    var result MyStruct
    err := mapstructure.Decode(m, &result)
    return result, err
}
```

Output:

```
map[Age:42 Name:foo Id:17]
{Id:17 Name:foo Age:42}
```

It has the advantage to work whatever your structure looks like, but it uses reflection internally. Actually, I don't see any "nice" way to do what you want without using reflection and/or repetitive code for each attribute of your structure. The downside, however, is that you will have to use capitalized attributes so that they would be exported to external packages.

#### Edit (to answer your question in the comments):

On my opinion, if you want to specify additional rules when "creating" the structure, it should be after the decoding operation.
For instance:

```
func CreateFromMap(m map[string]interface{}) (MyStruct, error) {
    var result MyStruct
    err := mapstructure.Decode(m, &result)
    if err != nil {
         return result, err
    }
    if result.Age <= 0 {
        result.Age = 0
    }
    if result.Name == "" {
        return result, errors.New("empty name is not allowed")
    }

    return result, err
}
```

This way, you will clearly separate the "conversion" part from your structure's specific rules processing.

Comment: I wanted to control what happens when one of the properties in the map doesn't exist. Let's assume `age` can be 0. I believe `mapstructure` will assign 0-value to `age` if it doesn't exist in the map. What if I want to return an error in some cases and allow 0-value in others? If there were a nullable integer type, that would solve my problem as I could figure out if the value doesn't exist or if it's actually zero.

Comment: But still, when you decode `{id: 0, name: "test"}`, `result.Age` will be 0. When you decode `{id: 0, name: "test", age: 0}`, `result.Age` will be 0 again. So I cannot know for sure if age exists in the map or not. Basically in mathematical terms, I need `Decode` to be a 1-to-1 function :)

Comment: Well, I agree this is a limitation of my solution ... I will try to find a workaround, but I can't think of any one right now.

Comment: I know this is old but the solution I believe will work is to set `result.Age = -1` before you decode the data so that if **Age** didn't exist in the data before `mapstrucutre` would not set it to 0. That way you could do this: `if result.Age < 0 { return results, errors.New("Age was not found in data")}`

Comment: **Update** My previous solution was incorrect and not best practice. The correct way to find out if `Age` was not set, is to convert you struct fields' using pointers.

`type MyStruct struct {
    Id   int
    Name *string
    Age  *int
}`

Now when you go to decode the data, if `Age` didn't exist its value will be set to `nil`.

`if result.Age == nil {
  return results, errors.New("Age was not found in data")
}`

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can just Marshal/Unmarshal, but property names should match

```
func CreateFromMap(m map[string]interface{}) (MyStruct, error) {
    data, _ := json.Marshal(m)
    var result MyStruct
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &result)
    return result, err
}
```